# Spring data setting up entitites

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-rest

I'm trying to use Spring data rest to build up my entities.
Here's my dependencies,

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version: '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.193'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
```

Here's my definition of entities,

```
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity{
    private String yguid;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Message> messages;

    protected User(){
        super();
        messages = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public User(String yguid, String name, String email) {
        this();
        this.yguid = yguid;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

The other,

```
@Entity
public class Message extends BaseEntity{

    private String senderId;
    private String receiverId;
    private String mediaId;
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    protected Message(){
        super();
    }

    public Message(String senderId, String receiverId, String mediaId) {
        this();
        this.senderId = senderId;
        this.receiverId = receiverId;
        this.mediaId = mediaId;
    }
}
```

These are my repositories,

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}

public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Long>{

}
```

This is my entry point.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I spin up the server,and go to localhost:8080/
this is all I get,

```
{
_links: {
profile: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/profile"
}
}
}
```

I'm expecting to see the entities too, as per the Spring tutorial. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: put a data.sql in your classpath and insert some data and see

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried annotating your repositories with `@RepositoryRestResource`? This should definately work.

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing is wrong with your code. Have you tried

> http://localhost:8080/users

or

> http://localhost:8080/messages

?